# Regex.Split Path

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have to split a path without file name to peaces.
Since source of path may be from different OS I think the best will be to use Regex.

Examples of Path can be:

```
     Dim _path As String = "C:\First\Second\third"
     Dim _path As String = "C:\\First\Second\third/"
     Dim _path As String = "C:/First/Second/third\"
     Dim _path As String = "C:/First\Second\third"
     Dim _path As String = "C://First/Second/third"
     Dim _path As String = "usr/bin/first/second/third"
     Dim _path As String = "/usr/bin/first/second/third/"
```

... and other similar variations.

In short, path have to be splited by and in this order "//" OR "\\" OR "/" OR "\"

Wanted result of string array will be:

```
    Splitted(0) = "C:"
    Splitted(1) = "First"
    Splitted(2) = "Second"
    Splitted(3) = "Third"

    OR

    Splitted(0) = "usr"
    Splitted(1) = "bin"
    Splitted(2) = "First"
    Splitted(3) = "Second"
    Splitted(4) = "Third"
```

How to write those Regex.Split code in VB.NET?

Comment: the regex you're looking for is [`[\\\/]+`](http://refiddle.com/gxv)

Comment: Thank you wolf. In case of trailing (last) slash this expression gives last empty string. Can this be repaired? Other situations this solves good! You can give me reply in form of "Answer" so I can vote for it.

Comment: I think it's better to use the approach proposed by Anton in his answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best and fastest way is to use Split method instead of RegExp.

```
Dim Splitted As String() = _path.Split(New [Char]() {"\"c, "/"c},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: When you need to perform such splits manually or in language with no Split() method I do the following: (1)replace all non-standard delimiter with a standard one (2)add extra first and extra last delimiter (3)replace all double/triple/etc occurrences (4)then use regex or charindex of whatever means the lauguage have